# Renaming files from a list of filenames

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, rename

I'm still very new to shell scripting so I'm sure this command is all kinds of wrong. I am trying to rename a folder of files to the names in a txt file. The precondition is that the filenames.txt and files in the folder are already organized to match up first line to first file in system. What I got was:

```
while read line; do echo -e "$line\n" | for f in *mkv do mv f $1; done < filenames.txt
```

but it didn't work. Can you guys help me correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have no algorithmic rule to rename the files (i.e. you actually need a file as input), I'd suggest to

1. create a txt file from list of files you want to rename, e.g. :

   find . -name "*.mkv" > files.txt
2. edit this file and add the new name after old one in each line, e.g.

   ./myfirst.mkv  ./mynewfirst.mkv
3. process this file:

   while read line; do eval mv $line; done < files.txt

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking inspiration from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26604

It sounds like you need to loop over both the file and the files in the directory at the same time:

```
DIR=./thefiledir
while : ; do
    read -r oldfile <&3
    read -r newfile <&4
    if [ -z "$oldfile" -o -z "$newfile" ]; then
        break
    fi
    mv $oldfile $newfile
done 3< <( find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort ) 4< filenames.txt
```

I don't know if you have the directory name in the `filenames.txt` file, so you may want to put an `echo` before the `mv` line to test that this will do what you want.

Also, I might try to do this another way... I'm not sure how you're generating the file with the new names, but as another answer suggests, you could loop over a file of old and new names or just read the names and apply some logic to create the new names.